# Keras NLP validation loss increases while training accuracy increases

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, word-embedding, hyperparameters

I have looked at other posts with similar problems and it seems that my model is overfitting. However, I've tried regularization, dropout, reducing parameters, decreasing the learning rate and changing the loss function, but nothing seems to help.

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential([
Embedding(max_words, 64),
Dropout(.5),
Bidirectional(GRU(64, return_sequences = True), merge_mode='concat'),
GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
Dense(64),
Dropout(.5),
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=25, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),shuffle=True)
```

And my training output:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_3 (Embedding)      (None, None, 64)          320000    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, None, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, None, 128)         49920     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_3 (Glob (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 378,241
Trainable params: 378,241
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 32ms/step - loss: 0.6952 - accuracy: 0.4939 - val_loss: 0.6923 - val_accuracy: 0.5240
Epoch 2/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6917 - accuracy: 0.5144 - val_loss: 0.6973 - val_accuracy: 0.4815
Epoch 3/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6709 - accuracy: 0.5881 - val_loss: 0.7164 - val_accuracy: 0.4784
Epoch 4/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6070 - accuracy: 0.6711 - val_loss: 0.7704 - val_accuracy: 0.4977
Epoch 5/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.5370 - accuracy: 0.7325 - val_loss: 0.8411 - val_accuracy: 0.4876
Epoch 6/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.4770 - accuracy: 0.7714 - val_loss: 0.9479 - val_accuracy: 0.4784
Epoch 7/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.4228 - accuracy: 0.8016 - val_loss: 1.0987 - val_accuracy: 0.4884
Epoch 8/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.3697 - accuracy: 0.8344 - val_loss: 1.2714 - val_accuracy: 0.4760
Epoch 9/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.3150 - accuracy: 0.8582 - val_loss: 1.4184 - val_accuracy: 0.4822
Epoch 10/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 31ms/step - loss: 0.2725 - accuracy: 0.8829 - val_loss: 1.6053 - val_accuracy: 0.4946
Epoch 11/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 31ms/step - loss: 0.2277 - accuracy: 0.9056 - val_loss: 1.8131 - val_accuracy: 0.4884
Epoch 12/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1929 - accuracy: 0.9253 - val_loss: 1.9327 - val_accuracy: 0.4977
Epoch 13/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1717 - accuracy: 0.9318 - val_loss: 2.2280 - val_accuracy: 0.4900
Epoch 14/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1643 - accuracy: 0.9324 - val_loss: 2.2811 - val_accuracy: 0.4915
Epoch 15/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1419 - accuracy: 0.9439 - val_loss: 2.4530 - val_accuracy: 0.4830
Epoch 16/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1255 - accuracy: 0.9521 - val_loss: 2.6692 - val_accuracy: 0.4992
Epoch 17/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1124 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 2.8106 - val_accuracy: 0.4892
Epoch 18/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1130 - accuracy: 0.9556 - val_loss: 2.6792 - val_accuracy: 0.4907
Epoch 19/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.1085 - accuracy: 0.9610 - val_loss: 2.8966 - val_accuracy: 0.5093
Epoch 20/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0974 - accuracy: 0.9656 - val_loss: 2.8636 - val_accuracy: 0.5147
Epoch 21/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0921 - accuracy: 0.9663 - val_loss: 2.9874 - val_accuracy: 0.4977
Epoch 22/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0888 - accuracy: 0.9685 - val_loss: 3.0295 - val_accuracy: 0.4969
Epoch 23/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0762 - accuracy: 0.9731 - val_loss: 3.0607 - val_accuracy: 0.4884
Epoch 24/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0842 - accuracy: 0.9692 - val_loss: 3.0552 - val_accuracy: 0.4900
Epoch 25/25
229/229 [==============================] - 7s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0816 - accuracy: 0.9693 - val_loss: 2.9571 - val_accuracy: 0.5015
```

My validation loss seems to always increases no matter what. I am trying to predict political affiliation from tweets. The dataset I am using has worked well on other models, so perhaps there is something wrong with my data preprocessing instead?

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('political_tweets.csv')
dataset.head()
dataset = pd.read_csv('political_tweets.csv')["tweet"].values
y_train = pd.read_csv('political_tweets.csv')["dem_or_rep"].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, y_train, test_size=0.15, shuffle=True)
print(x_train[0])
print(x_test[0])
max_words = 10000
max_len = 25

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = max_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n1234567890', lower=False,oov_token="<OOV>")

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, max_len, padding='post', truncating='post')

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_test)
x_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)
x_test = pad_sequences(x_test, max_len, padding='post', truncating='post')
```

I am really stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a binary classification and your validation accuracy is near 50%. It just means your model learnt nothing useful, it's equivalent to random prediction.

Your training accuracy is really high, which suggests your model is badly overfitted.

1. Don't apply dropout after embedding layer, it can mess everything up.
2. Remove this `Dense(64),` after `GlobalPooling`.
3. Use `recurrent_dropout` in GRU.
4. Train for fewer epochs.
5. Reduce vocabulary, remove stop words. Maybe there is too noise, as your sequence length is only 25, noisy stop words can fool the model.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

6. Your model is still overfitting. Try reducing embedding `output_dim` and  GRU `units` both with many combinations.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did as you instructed and it helped get my training accuracy up a lot faster, however the problem with increasing validation loss still persists. I cannot get the validation loss below around ~0.69 and it increases with every iteration. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you shuffle your validation data? `fit` only shuffles the training data, not the validation part, so try shuffling your full dataset first before `fit`.  Also try the new options.

Comment: I did all that and it still either overfits or underfits. I guess its just the data?

Comment: Yes, the data could be problematic with too much noise, maybe try with a new dataset or change your model to check if the dataset shows reasonable baseline accuracy.

Comment: I added more data preprocessing and I can get an accuracy of ~54% on the validation set but it quickly overfits and decreases after 2 epochs. Why is it overfitting so fast? Also thank you for all of the help, I've learned loads over the past few days.

Comment: Overfitting means your model is too complex. Why don't you get rid of lstm and try Conv1d?

Comment: Using conv1d makes my model converge a lot faster but my validation loss still cannot go below 0.69